# Having trouble with database schema causing logical issues using NOT LIKE with AND statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table information

`dbo.Attribute` (stores product attributes)

```
Item_Number, ATTR, VALUE
```

`dbo.Information` (sales data)

```
Item_Number,Title, Sold_Price
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
   Attribute.Item_Number, lower (Information.Item_Title)
   , min(Information.Sold_Price) as Price
FROM   
   Attribute 
INNER JOIN
   Information ON Attribute.Item_Number = Information.Item_Number
```

So the purpose of this query is that we have a bunch of sales data we'd like to cull to see what items we're not selling yet. For the sake of simplicity lets pretend we're selling hammers. `Item_Number` ties together sales & attribute data. They represent the same item.

We first filter out related sales data that we're not interested in, for instance Hammer Holsters.

```
where Information.Title not like '%holster%'
```

then we include all of the remaining hammer sales info

```
and Information.Title like '%hammer%'
```

Lastly we're trying to filter out the UPCs of the various hammers using queries like this

```
and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Attribute.VALUE, '-', ''), ' ', ''), '\\', ''), '/', ''), '&', ''), ',', '') not like '%HC456%'
and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Attribute.VALUE, '-', ''), ' ', ''), '\\', ''), '/', ''), '&', ''), ',', '') not like '%HC457%'
```

(I have since learned that using + between the words is more eloquent than repeating the whole line)

To ignore all results for certain hammers we're already selling. However, this is just removing the lines (rows) that contain this, not the whole `ITEM_NUMBER` which is what we're trying to exclude.

So for this example data set

```
Item_Number |   ATTR   | VALUE
------------+----------+--------
4789888     | UPC      | HC456
4789888     | Material | Leather
```

It is excluding the line with the UPC, but not the Item_Number entirely.

The the result is this output

```
 4789888, Material, Leather
```

How do I exclude all results for the Item_Number when there is a NOT LIKE match on Attribute.VALUE?

And is there a more eloquent way of ignoring everything except for alphanumeric information in a search than the way shown?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to the attributes table twice.

The first as the filter table, the second as a lookup. The first should be limited to "upc" records only and be the one your "not like" references. The second doesn't need to appear in the where clause at all.

sorry for not posting code, editing from phone

Comment: The UPC records are part of a lookup table (the example given).  I haven't been able to understand fully how to do this yet.  What I'm gathering I need to shuffle my "like '%hammer%' statement after the notlikes and do another from\where with the same join?  This would be called a sub-query?